# Objective-C: performSelector: vs. forwardInvocation:

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios5.1

pretty new to objective-c, but i've encountered what seems to be a pretty common situation: i want ClassA to ask ClassB to execute a method on an object that only ClassB knows about (and also using a method that is unknown to ClassA).

i've found two ways of doing this: **performSelector:** and **forwardInvocation:** - but i'd like to learn more and cement my understanding of each. i found this note in the apple developer docs:

> *The aSelector argument [in performSelector:] should identify a method that takes no
>   arguments. For methods that return anything other than an object, use
>   NSInvocation.*

..does that mean that methods that begin with *- (id)methodName* would use **performSelector:**, while say *- (int)nonObjectMethodName* would use **forwardInvocation:**?

also what about methods that return *(void)*? or methods that return non-id objects, e.g. *(NSString)*?

Comment: Note that -performSelector:withObject: also exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `-forwardInvocation:` is used as part of the message-forwarding mechanism. Don't worry about message forwarding, as it's really only used by proxy objects and odds are good you'll never need to use it and know you're using it.

`-performSelector:` assumes the message's return type is `id` or compatible, and so is not safe if it is used to send a message whose return type is different (e.g. wider than a pointer such as a `long long` on 32-bit systems, or returned via a different register/address such as a `float` or large `struct`.)

If you want to indirectly send a message like that, you can *create* an instance of the `NSInvocation` class and then send it `-invoke`. The return value is then stored in the invocation object and can be accessed through it. `-forwardInvocation:` is never used by you in this scenario.

Generally speaking, if you find yourself using `-performSelector:`, you are probably be dealing with an anti-pattern. In this case, you're trying to send a message that `ClassA` doesn't formally know about. The alternate solution is to expose those private methods.

---

If you own both `ClassA` and `ClassB`, you can create a "private" header for `ClassB` that includes the private methods you want to use. If somebody else (e.g. Apple) owns `ClassB`, you are dealing with undocumented APIs and may need to look for another approach, as Apple will reject an app that uses such APIs.

To create a private header, go into Xcode and create a new header file. Name it something like "ClassB+Internal.h" or "ClassB+PrivateMethodsForMeOnly.h". Treat it as private to your project--nobody gets to use it unless they are peers (same subproject or library or component) with `ClassB`. In this new header, add the following:

```
#import "ClassB.h" // so we get the original class definition

@interface ClassB (PrivateMethodsForMeOnly)
- (double)someMethod;
- (const struct low_level_c_type_t)otherMethod:(int)i;
// etc. etc. etc.
@end
```

And in `ClassA.m` (*not* `ClassA.h` unless you want to expose these methods to everybody who uses `ClassA`!) add the following line in your include section:

```
#import "ClassB+PrivateMethodsForMeOnly.h"
```

`ClassA` will thereafter have access to those methods in the new category.

Comment: The private header dance is a beautiful thing when you're building a framework or library. In a single project, it's a little silly since all the classes have full access to each other. Still, enforcing this sort of rigidity forces you to think a little more about your class hierarchy, and that's never a waste of time.

Comment: i do own both classes - but the primary reason for this question is really in pursuit of proper mvc or mvc+store architecture - in my case, ClassA is a custom UITableViewCell class being 'called' by a UITableViewController class (ClassB). the object being manipulated is a simple NSObject class - but in my application so far, only ClassB has access to that NSObject class, and I want to keep it that way..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's several questions.

First of all, forget "forwardInvocation" -- that's pretty much a method that you only need to make proxy objects.

Invocations are created with [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature...], then filled with the selector, arguments and the target object, and eventually you just "invoke" it. That's how you can send (and even store) any method call.

performselector exists in several variations, some of which takes parameters, call it after a delay, or run the method on another thread. It's a more "direct" call -- NSInvocation is an object that you can keep around like any other object until you need it, whereas "performselector" pretty much runs the method right away.

As for return values, I generally stick to what the documentation says; if it tells me the method should return an id I return an object (any object pointer is ok, so NSString* is fine. Returning nil is also ok, which pretty much covers the 'void' case), not void and not int.

Also, keep in mind that calling performselector isn't all THAT common; in most cases you just hardcode the call as in "[MyObject SomeMethod:SomeParameter];". Calling a performSelector-style method is for special cases -- the target/action stuff on GUI objects is one such case, where the selector to be called is stored in the object, so it obviously can't be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `-forwardInvocation:` is to let an object attempt to send a message it doesn't recognize some other object instead of just giving up.  An NSInvocation contains not only the selector, but all of the parameters of the message. `NSProxy` uses it, but if I recall correctly, we had it before Distributed Objects. It's one way to implement delegation for "everything this class can't handle".

You should read the [section on message forwarding in the Objective-C docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH105-SW1)